# UTF-8 Space showing as a box in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, utf-8

In the below screenshots of a webpage, this is some UTF-8 text, which displays perfectly in firefox but in Chrome - there is a box in place of space. Also, if I increase the zoom level by 1 in Chrome - the problem goes away.

How to fix it with PHP?

[Chrome Problem](http://www.thevakeel.com/utf_space_problem_chrome.png)

[FireFox Fine](http://www.thevakeel.com/utf_space_firefox.png)

[Update] Some more Info :

```
$s = utf8_to_unicode_code($desc);

for($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
        echo $s[$i]."\n";
}

function utf8_to_unicode_code($utf8_string)
          {
              $expanded = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-32", $utf8_string);
              return unpack("L*", $expanded);
          }
```

The above code outputs :

```
-131072
1006632960
1644167168
1040187392
118030336
906559488
805896192
604569600
536870912
352911360
1191772160
940113920
536870912
973078528
536870912
671678464
805896192
1191772160
34144256
```

Any deductions we can make with it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that's been inserted mid-document?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, how do I check that? And why does it work fine in Firefox?

Comment: Easiest (sadly not _easy_) is probably to save the source and open in a HEX editor to look at the contents. Alternately, how are you generating the output that breaks in PHP? Reading from a file and just outputting it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am fetching a url and displaying it. But note that the problem disappears in Chrome if I increase the zoom level by 1. In firefox there is no problem at all.

Comment: Try outputting the [ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) value of the first few characters in the string you're fetching to see if the URL is returning a BOM.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Just see my update and see if you can deduce anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your first character is `0xfffe0000` which is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Apparently it's displayed in some fonts/font sizes and not others.

To remove it from your string before output, you can for example check the example [here](http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/04/detecting-utf-bom-byte-order-mark/) that detects it in a string and removes it if necessary.

```php
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 == strncmp($str, $bom, 3)) {
    // echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8\n";
    $str = substr($str, 3);
}
```